# Pass onActivityResult() data to the same Fragment which is not yet ready

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I am using a `Fragment` to start a new `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()`, I am getting the result `(Bundle)` in `onActivityResult`() method.Since `onActivityResult`() called before `onResume`().I want to make sure, I keep/save the `Bundle` properly so that when `Fragment's` `onResume()` gets called, I get the kept/saved result to perform further action.

What are the different ways to achieve this. I tried using getArguments()/setArguments(), but that seems to be not the right way to achieve this.

Comment: What does this means?

Comment: Why do you not save result in simple class field (your fragment class)

Comment: I want to try the proper way, using variables or methods may also lead to crash, since Fragment itself may not be available while using member variables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mResultBundle = data.getExtras(); //mResultBundle is in fragment 
            //scope
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(mResultBundle != null){
       // process saved bundle from activity result here

       // don't forget to set it back to null once you are done
       mResultBundle = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to try the proper way, using variables or methods may also lead to crash, since Fragment itself may not be available while using member variables.

Comment: Whenever the onActivityResult method is called. There will be a fragment instance. On that instance you assign the result as a member variable. What do you think could go wrong in this scenario?

Comment: There may not be a fragment instance, Since onActivityResult() gets called before fragment is ready. Read this : http://steveliles.github.io/android_activity_lifecycle_gotcha.html

Comment: If you are using the **Fragment's** `onActivityResult` method, In order for that method to be called by the system, there has to be an instance of the fragment, right? Or am I missing something obvious here!

Comment: Not sure !! You might be right. But is there any other way I can use , For ex: Bundle to pass in onResume()

Comment: I provided the easy solution here. If you want you can use SharedPreference or a Singleton ViewModel class to hold the data till you hit onResume

Comment: The solution you have provided, is simple one and I've already tried before posting question. My question is, how can I pass data from onActivityResult() to onResume()

Comment: You cannot pass any extra info directly to onResume. Your only option is to save the data somewhere until the lifecycle method is hit by the system.