# How can i pass onActivityResult data in activity?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 900) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b=data.getExtras();
            if(b!=null){
                Playlist playlist = (Playlist) b.getSerializable("obj");
                int playlistId = data.getIntExtra("PLAYLIST_ID", 0);

                Log.d("---->Data ID", String.valueOf(playlistId));
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I send that `playlistId` Value in `onCreate()` method?

Comment: You cant call by yourself onCreate() Method. what exactly do you want to do

Comment: You can't send this to `onCreate` method. Try calling method where it is going to be used from here.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35477167/3533289

Comment: that playlist id pass in my button click listener

Comment: i got that playlist id in log but when i use that id in click that time it will be 0

Comment: if playlistId is 0 it means the value is empty, show your result method please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ResultActivity:**

```
  intent.putExtra("yourKeyName", "hello");
    setResult(900, intent);
```

**Get the result:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode== 900) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            String hello = data.getStringExtra("yourKeyName");  
        }
    }
```

You dont have to create a new Bundle, just get extra content from the "Intent data".
Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it posssible to access hello somewhere out of onActivityResult after setting it? For example, what if it was required to pass hello to another activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode== 900) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b=data.getExtras();
            if(b!=null){
                Playlist playlist = (Playlist) b.getSerializable("obj");
                int playlistId = data.getIntExtra("PLAYLIST_ID", 0);

                Log.d("---->Data ID", String.valueOf(playlistId));
            }
        }
    }

use this in another activity to get the result back 

Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.putExtra("key",value);
setResult(900,intent );
```